# Congruency of Triangles, To prove BE = CF

Tags: triangles, proof-explanation

I am preparing for my maths exam on saturday, I could not find a satisfactory answer to a question I am stuck on.

http://i66.tinypic.com/nqxwn7.jpg

Given an isosceles triangle ABC in which AB = AC. If E and F be midpoints of AC and AB respectively, prove BE = CF.

I know the constructed line EF is parallel to BC but I could not prove the same satisfactorily. Thanks.

Comment: Everything is symmetric with respect to the perpendicular bisector of $BC$.

Comment: Or you may invoke the full power of Stewart's theorem, then write an article for the future edition of *Mathematics made difficult*.

Comment: yes but I'm looking for a proof with triangle congruence conditions like SSS or SAS (side angle side), ASA which is how I need to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the $\Delta$s ABE, ACF

$AB=AC$ given

$AE=AF$ half of AC, AB resp.

$\angle BAE=\angle CAF$ common

Therefore $\Delta ABE\cong \Delta ACF$ two sides and included angle

In particular, $BE=CF$

$QED$

You don't need to prove $FE\|BC$, nor to quote the base angles of an isoceles triangle theorem.

In fact the same proof applies whenever points $E$ and $F$ are equidistant from $A$ on the sides $AC$,$AB$ (not necessarily the mid points). This is used in Euclid's proof of Proposition 5 (the base angles of an isoceles triangle theorem), though he could, more elegantly, have used the fact that $\Delta ABC\cong \Delta ACB$ (two sides and the included angle).

Answer (score 0):

The base angles of an isosceles triangle are equal. SAS proves triangles are equal. Then corresponding parts of congruent triangles are equal finishes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is like this (by congruency):

In $\triangle BEC$ and $ \triangle CFB$
$$BC \cong CB $$
$$\angle ABC \cong\angle ECB$$
$$AB\cong AC \Leftrightarrow BF \cong EC$$
By $SAS$ congruence criterion
$$\triangle BEC \cong \triangle CFB$$
So $BE \cong CF $ (Corresponding parts of Congruent Triangles)